# ElasticSearch RestHighLevelClient search with wildcard not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to search with wildcard "*" in Java application, using ElasticSearch's RestHighLevelClient API. But not getting any match.

Data on the index:

```
JEAN
JEAN CHRISTOPHER
JEAN SOMETHING ELSE
```

Searching using URL API:

```
http://mylocal-es-server.com/myindex/_search?q=firstName:JEAN*&pretty // 2 hits
```

JAVA code (updated):

```
public SearchResponse preciseSearch(PreciseSearchRequest req) throws IOException {
    // convert my req to org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest:
    SearchRequest searchReq = createSearchRequest(req);
    // print searchReq (see below)
    return restHighLevelClient.search(searchReq, RequestOptions.DEFAULT); // returns 0 hit
}
```

PRINT searchReq:

```
{"from":0,"size":1000,"query":{"query":"(firstName:(\"JEAN*\"))","fields:[],"type":"best_fields","default_operator":"or","max_determinzed_states":10000,"enable_position_increments":true,"fuzziness":"AUTO","fuzzy_prefix_length":0,"fuzzy_max_expansions":50,"phrase_slop":0,"escape":false,"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"boost":1.0}},"sort":[{"age":{"order":"desc"}}]}
```

Index mapping:

```
"firstName" : { "type": "keyword" }
```

I suspect it is due to type = keyword instead of text. But then how come searching using URL works fine?

Any pointers appreciated! I'm a ES beginner!

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share your `resthighlevelclient` java code? That would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the issue..

There was a piece of code that wraps the value with double quote. The double quote works fine on its own, but when there's wildcard, it doesn't work.

I had:

```
"query":"(firstName:(\"JEAN*\"))"
```

It should be:

```
"query":"(firstName:(JEAN*))"
```

Answer (score 1):

> "firstName" : { "type": "keyword" }

In Elastic Search, Keyword fields are not analyzed and they are case sensitive.

a) **Indexing Time:** 'JEAN' will be indexed as 'JEAN' and not jean

b) **Search Time:** 'JEAN' will look for 'JEAN' and not 'jean' or 'Jean' or 'jEAN' etc

However, ES also provides support for keyword normalization. See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html) and play around with it.

> ... "query":{"query_string":{"query":"(firstName:("jean*"))" ... //
> 0 hit

0 hits as JEAN is not normalized & analyzed before storing (case-sensitivity).

> ... "query":{"query_string":{"query":"(firstName:("JEAN"))" ... // 1
> hit

1 hit due to exact match with JEAN.

> ... "query":{"query_string":{"query":"(firstName:("JEAN*"))" ... //
> 0 hit

**It is returning 3 hits for me as it should.**

Comment: Thank you for the info on Normalizer. However I actually wanted my data to be uppercase, and when I search, my query is in uppercase also.